# Using LARGE JSON Data Source with Apache Flink and Python (2 questions)

Tags: java, python, apache-flink

Flink's Batch Python API, Version 1.2 supports

- read_text(path)
- read_csv(path, type)
- from_elements(*args)

And some specific data types: (int, float, bool, string) and byte arrays.

Python is pretty strong with dictionaries, and reading a json file through `json.load(file)` creates a dict type variable, but as far as i searched, dictionary manipulation isn't supported by flink atm.

**Question num0:** So, besides parsing strings and trying to mess with regular expressions, is there any other way to handle large json files with flink's python api?

I was thinking to preprocess my json file using lists and in combination with from_elements(*args) to achieve something.

Handling Objects seems to be a problem with Python+Flink as well.

**Question num1:** Is switching to Java my best bet?

I would like to have an easy way to handle json data, as well as using objects derived from these data.

Comment: You could try providing a serializer for dictionaries; this should allow you to use them in your jobs. Note that you would still need a key-extractor whenever you want to use a groupBy or similar. The serializer has to implement Collector#Serializer, which takes an object and returns a byte string The deserializer has to implement Iterator#Deserializer, specifically the deserialize method. This method receives an input stream on which you can call read(x) to read x bytes., The serializer/deserializer can be registered using Environment#register_custom_type().

Comment: Could i use pickle with python api to serialize my objects, or have i to use struct pack and unpack?

Comment: You should be able to implement a serializer that internally uses pickle. Note that you still need to know how much data you have to read.

Comment: ok. By the way, In Data Types section, Python API Documentation, the Object example uses register_custom_type(), but looking https://github.com/apache/flink/blob/master/flink-libraries/flink-python/src/main/python/org/apache/flink/python/api/flink/plan/Environment.py, i see register_type(). Do i have to write something in the Environment.py?

Comment: register_type() is the correct method, the docs are apparently outdated.

Comment: There's also a test here https://github.com/apache/flink/blob/master/flink-libraries/flink-python/src/test/python/org/apache/flink/python/api/test_main.py that uses this method. Look for #Custom serialization.

Comment: thanks! I'll take a look

Comment: Were you able to find solution to this @Uheq?

Comment: @pratyushsharma i switched to java. Then i used a 3rd party api for handling json data such as gson and loaded these data into java native data structures. Then i mapped my data with tuple objects provided by Flink's Java APIs. Not sure if it's ideal solution, but it worked.